# html a href syntax error.unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: html

```
echo "[<a href='book2.php';"  $row["start_station"] . "/" . $row["end_station"] . "/" . $row["travel_date"] . "/" . $row["time_of_day"] . "/" . $row["seats_free"] . "/" . $row["train_id"]."</a>"]; "<br>";
```

Gives me an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'
```

It seems like I am missing `;`, but none of my corrections worked. Can anybody identify and fix the problem?

Comment: You are missing quote tags `""` around your ending `</a>` tag

Comment: added the quotes - same error